# Generating data.frame objects with a for loop

Tags: r

Is there a way to dynamically create a data.frame (or any object for that matter) without it being initialized as a variable? For example:

```
for(x in 1:26) { 
paste(letters[x]) <- df[x]
}
```

Such that you have new variables a,b,c,d,...,z?

Comment: care to share some R code the runs? i) what is `df` here? ii) there isn't a `paste<-()` function. So your pseudocode is not very illustrative and the description of what you want is a bit lacking. Can you expand on the Q?

Comment: Looks like you posted this comment at about the same time I got it sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching around, I found it:

```
for(x in 1:26) { 
assign(paste(letters[x]), df[x])
}
```

Comment: Can you utilize lists for this task?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f